# When are you not on TeX.SX?

Tags: discussion, community

The question is:

> When am I not in TeX.SX?

Usually as soon as I have access to the Internet, I connect to this site more like how people do with facebook. What is your case?

Comment: This Q, may be as an answer in [TeX Community Polls](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1564/15717).

Answer (score 20):

I think I'm not on TeX.sx when... well... I have no idea. `:)` After all, last time I wasn't here was April 23, 2011, according to my profile. `:)`

Comment: I think up voting this post is the analogy for the Facebook "like". Voted.

Answer (score 17):

When

- I have no internet connection.
- I have no TeX distro plus a text editor installed.
- I have no electricity.
- I have no money to pay many bills so I have to work 24 hours a day.
- The top 50 members resign from this site.
- Microsoft releases a better typesetting system than (La)TeX. It is not necessarily free of charge.
- ...
- All copies of (La)TeX distributions on the earth are destroyed by Aliens.

Answer (score 6):

When I wasn't yet registered!!

Answer (score 5):

When I’m on SciFi.SE. *ducks*

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I'm usually only on when I'm thinking about LaTeX. So if I'm writing or editing something I'll often log in. However, if I'm trapped in MS world land or not writing anything, then I'll forget to log in.